# get wanted data from a text file with python without using splits

Tags: python, file

Hello i have a that file:

```
WORKERS = yovel:10.0.0.6,james:10.0.0.7
BLACKLIST = 92.122.197.45:ynet,95.1.2.2:twitter
```

I'm trying to write a function in python that will get the worker IP and returns the worker name like this:

```
workername = getName(ip)
```

The only method i thougt to do it is with splits(using `.split(":")` , `.split(",")` etc.) but it will be very long code and not smart.

is there a shorter way to do it?

Comment: How is using `split` "very long" and "not smart"? Please include your code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `re`:

```
import re
def getName(ip, content = open('filename.txt').read()):
  _r = re.findall('\w+(?=:{})'.format(ip), content)
  return _r[0] if _r else None

print(getName('10.0.0.6'))
```

Output:

```
'yovel'
```

Note, however, it is slightly more robust to use `split`:

```
def getName(ip):
  lines = dict(i.strip('\n').split(' = ') for i in open('filename.txt')]
  d = {b:a for a, b in map(lambda x:x.split(':'), lines['WORKERS'].split(','))}
  return d.get(ip)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `split()` doesn't look too bad here:

```
def getName(ip_address, filename='file.txt', line_type='WORKERS'):
    with open(filename) as in_file:
        for line in in_file:
            name, info = [x.strip() for x in line.strip().split('=')]

            if name == line_type:
                info = [x.split(':') for x in info.split(',')]
                lookup = {ip: name for name, ip in info}
                return lookup.get(ip_address)
```

Which works as follows:

```
>>> getName('10.0.0.6')
'yovel'
```